# Setting Racket Geiser Emacs Path

Tags: emacs, racket, geiser

I'm trying to get Geiser's REPL to work in Emacs, but it doesn't seem to be able to find Racket.

`racket` is on my path, but anytime I type

```
run-geiser
```

followed by

```
racket
```

it complains:

> Unable to start REPL: Searching for program: no such file or directory, racket

I read in the Geiser docs that I may have to manually tell Geiser where to find `racket`, but I can't tell where to configure this property of Geiser.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just for reference: Scott probably saw the configuration option in http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/geiser_3.html#impl_002dbinary

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, so I added:

```
(setq geiser-racket-binary "/home/user/racket/bin/racket")
```

to my `.emacs` file after loading `geiser.el`.

I was expecting a configuration file somewhere to set this.

Thanks.

Comment: `.emacs` *is* the main file to configure your Emacs...  BTW, another option is to either add that `/home/user/racket/bin` to your PATH, or add symlinks from a directory that is in your PATH (like `/home/user/bin`).

Comment: Ya, the problem is that the path isn't being picked up.  I have racket in my path, and can type it anywhere, but geiser can't seem to find it unless I put in the explicit binary path above.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for future people having a hard time getting it to find the Racket executable despite it being in your path, you can simply use the `executable-find` function.

This searches your path and returns the absolute path to the executable, which is what the `geiser-racket-binary` function wants.  So this is an alternative to explicitly setting the absolute path:

```
(setq geiser-racket-binary (executable-find "Racket"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, adding the location of the Racket executable to the "path" environment variable which is part of Windows will allow Geiser/Emacs to find the Racket Executable.

Comment: Note that the OP stated that racket was in its path env variable.