# How to run racket with geiser: getting error:Can't exec program: /Applications/Racketv6.0/DrRacket.app

Tags: emacs, racket, read-eval-print-loop, geiser

I am new to Emacs and I am having a bit of trouble. I am looking to run `racket` from Emacs using Geiser. I told Emacs where `racket` is as follows:

```
(setq geiser-racket-binary "/Applications/Racket\ v6.0/DrRacket.app")
```

(I took this from StackOverflow question: [Setting Racket Geiser Emacs Path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9237291/3563207).)

I start by compiling the racket code that is saved. However, when I attempt to hit <kbd>M-x</kbd> followed by `run-geiser`, it then prompts me for a Scheme implementation. At this point I type `racket`. Emacs now opens a racket REPL buffer and in that buffer it leaves the error:

> Can't exec program: /Applications/Racketv6.0/DrRacket.app .

If it helps, here is my `.emacs` file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.

 '(geiser-repl-startup-time 20000)
 '(package-archives (quote (("gnu" . "elpa gnu packages website") ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/"))))    
 '(package-directory-list (quote ("/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/site-lisp/elpa")))    
 '(python-python-command "/usr/local/bin/python3"))

(setq geiser-racket-binary "/Applications/Racket\ v6.0/DrRacket.app")    
(setq-default cursor-type 'bar)

(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "controlDarkShadowColor" :foreground "Green" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 120 :width normal :foundry "apple" :family "Monaco")))))

(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives 
     '("marmalade" .
      "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referencing the wrong executable.

"DrRacket" is an IDE (with a graphical user interface) for editing Racket code. From `man drracket`:

> DrRacket is the Racket programming environment.

Try setting `geiser-racket-binary` to the location of the `racket` executable (which is the "core Racket implementation") instead.

---

**EDIT**

If the naming scheme of the Mac installation of Racket is anything like the one used for the Linux installation, there should be a binary called `Racket` or `racket` in a location similar to where you can find the `DrRacket` (or `drracket`) binary:

```
$ locate racket
...
/usr/bin/drracket
/usr/bin/gracket
/usr/bin/gracket-text
/usr/bin/racket
...
```

(Not suggesting that *you* will find the binaries in `/usr/bin/`, just trying to illustrate that there is a good chance all binaries that are possibly relevant are located in the same directory.)

Answer (score 0):

On OS X `xxx.app` is technically a directory. The actual executable file is located in `Content/MacOS/xxx` (if my memory serves me correctly).

*EDIT:* In other words, you should write something like:

```
(setq geiser-racket-binary "/Applications/Racket\ v6.0/DrRacket.app/Content/MacOS/DrRacket")
```

Note: I'n not at my Mac so I can't verify the details right now.

Comment: I suppose that means that I would want for replace "/Applications/Racket\ v6.0/DrRacket.app" with the actual executable file??? Does the "xxx" refer to "/Applications/Racket\ v6.0/DrRacket.app" or some sub-string of this (or something else)? Also does "Content" and "MacOS" refer to something or themselves literally?? I apologize for my confusions, and thank you for your answer, I think you at least got a little closer to understanding what needs to be done.