# Running racket with emacs?

Tags: emacs, racket, geiser

I installed Geiser from source  and following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237291/setting-racket-geiser-emacs-path) set the path to drracket.
Here is my part of my .emacs file. I'm on a GNU/linux distribution.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Geiser
;downloaded geiser from git rep and make install
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
(require 'geiser-install)

(setq geiser-racket-binary "/usr/racket/bin/drracket")
```

In emacs when I `M-x run-racket` on emacs I get the following error:

```
drracket: unknown switch: -i
```

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the solution was to use

```
(setq geiser-racket-binary "/usr/racket/bin/racket")
```

instead of :

```
 (setq geiser-racket-binary "/usr/racket/bin/drracket")
```